# Check if instance of model was created today?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to check if an instance of a model was already created today?

I want it so only one instance of the model should be created each day so if a new one is created, any instance that was already created that day is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Query directly into the db to retrieve only today's records:

```
Model.where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now.end_of_day)
```

You can also process it at Ruby end (*If you actually want, but not recommended*):

```
Model.all.select{|m| m.created_at.today?}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to first check if there are any instances that were created today, and if so, destroy them all. After that, you can create your new instance.

```
def destroy_todays
  Model.where(created_at: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day).destroy_all
end

def create_todays(attrs)
  destroy_todays
  Model.create(attrs)
end
```

So, any time you want to create todays instance, you guarantee you are first destroying any other instances that were created today.